# Continue test if a click error occurs

Tags: javascript, xpath, error-handling, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm running CasperJS with PhantomJS. I have it going to a url and clicking on an element based on XPath. This could happen several times without a problem, until, I suspect there is a delay in the page loading, it can't find the XPath, it throws an error and stops the test. I would like it to continue through the error. I don't want to wait+click any longer than I already am, as there are many clicks going on, and an error can be at a random click, waiting on every click is counter productive.

I have tried putting the whole test into a try catch, it wouldn't catch.

The only handling I could find just gave out more information on the error, still stopped the test.

Answer (score 1):

I would wait for the selector you want to run, with a short timeout. In the success function do your click, in the timeout function report the problem (or do nothing at all).

For instance:

```
casper.waitForSelector('a.some-class', function() {
    this.click('a.some-class');
    }, function onTimeout(){
    this.echo("No a.some-class found, skipping it.");
    },
    100);   //Only wait 0.1s, as we expect it to already be there
});
```

(If you were already doing a `casper.wait()` just before this, then replace that with the above code, and increase the timeout accordingly.)

Comment: @Artjom, I don't know - I cannot see anything definitive in the casper documentation one way or the other. I'm sure a timeout of 1ms would work; the `100` was just for example.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot catch an error in something that is executed asynchronously. All `then*` and `wait*` functions are step functions which are asynchronous.

Darren Cook provides a [good reliable solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27341836). Here are two more which may work for you.

### `casper.options.exitOnError`

CasperJS provides an option to [disable exiting on error](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#exitonerror). It work reliably. The complete error with stacktrace is printed in the console, but the script execution continues. Although, this might have adverse effects when you also have other errors on which you may want to stop execution.

### try-catch

Using a try-catch block works in CasperJS, but only on synchronous code. The following code shows an example where only the error message is printed without stacktrace:

```
casper.then(function() {
    try {
        this.click(selector);
    } catch(e){
        console.log("Caught", e);
    }
});
```

or more integrated:

```
// at the beginning of the script
casper.errorClick = function(selector) {
    try {
        this.click(selector);
    } catch(e){
        console.log("Caught", e);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
};

// in the test
casper.then(function() {
    this.errorClick("someSelector");
});
```